# Want to populate a combobox with two related tables in access

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2010

I have a two related tables in my access DataBase, ***Table1*** and ***Table2***.
In Table1 I have "***Cd_Table1***"(primaryKey) and "***Cd_Table2***"(foreignKey).
In Table2 I have "***Cd_Table2***"(primaryKey) and "***Nm_Atr***"(string).
I want to populate a combobox with these two tables, but the "*DisplayMemberPath*" needs to be "***Nm_Atr***" and the "*ValueMemberPath*" needs to be "***Cd_Table1***".

My code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Table1.Cd_AtributosNormais, Table1.Nm_Atr, Table2.Cd_AtributosNormais FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.Cd_AtributosNormais = Table2.Cd_AtributosNormais", cn);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(reader);
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Nm_Atr"] = "";
            table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

            this.btCmbAtkBaAtr1.DataContext = table.DefaultView;
            this.btCmbAtkBaAtr1.DisplayMemberPath = "Nm_Atr";
            this.btCmbAtkBaAtr1.SelectedValuePath = "Cd_AtributosNormais";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
        }
```

Where is the error and why the combobox do not display nothing?
I'm already opened a connection and I'm using C# to program and access 2010.

Comment: Give it a try and tell us exactly where you're having problems.  As it is now your 'question' is just a request to have someone else do your work for you.

Comment: First your query is not well written, SELECT Table1.Cd_AtributosNormais, Table2.Nm_Atr FROM Table1 Left outer join  Table2 on Table1.Cd_AtributosNormais = Table2.Cd_AtributosNormais ... You not need to select same field twice.. Second do you have problem with server side code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if it helps..

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Table1.Cd_AtributosNormais as Cd_AtributosNormais, Table2.Nm_Atr as Nm_Atr FROM Table1 Left outer join Table2 on Table1.Cd_AtributosNormais = Table2.Cd_AtributosNormais", cn);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(reader);
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Nm_Atr"] = "";
            table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

            this.btCmbAtkBaAtr1.DataContext = table.DefaultView;
            this.btCmbAtkBaAtr1.DisplayMemberPath = "Nm_Atr";
            this.btCmbAtkBaAtr1.SelectedValuePath = "Cd_AtributosNormais";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
        }
```